# How to stretch items in horizontal recycler view to match parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 items in recycler view, they are aligned to the left and look like this:

[image]

But I want them to strectch and fill the screen and look like this:

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this with **Recycler View**? I don't want to tuse **Linear** or **Constraint** Layout.

Comment: you should post your code first

Comment: You can use Grid Layout manager in Recyclerview and set span count = <your_item_count>(here it is 3)
It will good if you can post your actual source code.

Comment: I didn't started development so I don't have the code, it's just default behaviour of very simple horizontal recycler view with Linear Layout Manager. I'll try grid layuot manager.

Comment: Grid Layout manager worked, thank you!